# How to align one digit number to be on the middle of the below two digit numbers with html and css

Tags: html, css

Having the following code snippet:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div><p class='mb-2'>This is the title!</p>
<div>
  <p><span>5</span> <i class='fa fa-sort-down'></i><span> = this is some text</span></p>
  <p><span>24</span> <i class='fa fa-sort-down'></i><span>  = this is another text over here</span></p>
  <p><span>31</span> <i class='fa fa-sort-down'></i><span> = the same</span></p>
</div>
</div>
```

As it can be seen in the code, `5` is exactly above `2`. It must be above `24`, like in the middle, between them.

I've tried to add display flex to the span and then `aling-items` or `aling-self` and set it to `center` but didn't work.

Any suggestions

Comment: not a job for Flexbox, a job for CSS-Grid. Alternatively give all spans the same width and use `text-align: center`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a table layout and you don't need a fixed width:

```css
.table {
  display: table;
}
.table p {
  display: table-row;
}
.table p span:first-child {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div><p class='mb-2'>This is the title!</p>
<div class="table">
  <p><span>5</span> <i class='fa fa-sort-down'></i><span> = this is some text</span></p>
  <p><span>24</span> <i class='fa fa-sort-down'></i><span>  = this is another text over here</span></p>
  <p><span>31</span> <i class='fa fa-sort-down'></i><span> = the same</span></p>
  <p><span>999</span> <i class='fa fa-sort-down'></i><span> = the same</span></p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about making all `spans` the same `width` and then centering the text inside those spans (you'll need to set `display: inline-block;` to set the `span` `width`):

```css
.number{
  display: inline-block;
  width:18px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div><p class='mb-2'>This is the title!</p>
<div>
  <p><span class="number">5</span> <i class='fa fa-sort-down'></i><span> = this is some text</span></p>
  <p><span class="number">24</span> <i class='fa fa-sort-down'></i><span>  = this is another text over here</span></p>
  <p><span class="number">31</span> <i class='fa fa-sort-down'></i><span> = the same</span></p>
</div>
</div>
```